# How to properly overlay one container over another (responsively)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

There are two containers. One of which is the main (essentially, the parent) container. Another is a child container that serves as a tag for categorizing the content. The tag container needs to be positioned at the top right corner of the main content container, pushed over a bit from the right and where the top border of the main container splits the tag container in half. Below, I have been able to more or less do so. But my question is how can I ensure that the top border of the main container perfectly coincides with the center of the tag container?

Including a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/container-overlay-vrutw2?file=/src/styles.css:143-509) to the codesandbox for convenience.

```
<div className="main">
  <div className="tag">TAG</div>
  <p>MAIN CONTENT</p>
</div>
```

```
.main {
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 16px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.tag {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 24px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `top:0;transform:translateY(-50%)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `div` with `position: relative` explicitly, then other `divs` inside it will be relative to it.

By applying `position: absolute` to the child `div` you will produce that it will be at the position `(0, 0)` of the parent container (counting from top-left). Then, if you apply `top: height/2` to your child container, you will assure that it will always be centered with the top border of your parent container. Check the snippet below.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: -20px; /* must the half of the height.*/
  right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you.